# How to create multiple scroll-able sections within a twitter-bootstrap fluid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap fluid layout for my site.  I have a collapse/expand accordion and inside of one of the sections, I have three columns that I would like to be separately scroll-able.  These columns currently expand to the full height of their content, but I'd instead like them to expand to the viewport (viewable page) and show a scrollbar to get to the rest (when it is not already all visible).

The scrollbars will show up if I set the column to: `overflow: auto;` `height: 500px;`

I don't want to set the height; however, I want it to be set to whatever fits in the viewport.

I understand you can set a div's height to 100% in order to expand to the viewport; however, it has to depend on a containing elements height.  I'm not sure how to deal with this within Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

appart `$('#collapseOne').on('shown', sizing());` not resizing properly if you resize after loading.

This is working pretty much ok on desktop.

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/MwzvD/17/